# How do afferent mechanoreceptors work on the finger pads?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, human-physiology, sensation, touch

I'm having some difficulty understanding how the afferent signals are sensed in the finger pads. My understanding is that for mechanoreceptors, as the indenting force increases, their effective response also increases. Additionally, as contact area increases, so does the overall stimulus area and hence a larger response amplitude from the mechanoreceptor afferents should be found.

However, the results shown in [this article](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/12/3/827.full.pdf) in the Journal of Neuroscience that discusses this physiology shows contradicting results. In this article, the closer the dot spacing (1 mm or less) and the higher the contact area the lesser the receptors seem to fire, and stop firing altogether at about 1 mm dot spacing?

Why would this occur?

Comment: I made some edits to your question... not trying to change your question but only clarify it for other users so you can get a good answer from someone.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a *"please hold my hand and walk me through this paper/concept/idea"* site. I strongly suggest you take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a really tough question to answer. I skimmed through the linked paper (authorative authors there!) and the last part of the discussion goes into more detail on this question, including references to other papers. I may get back to this question, but it's going to take me a while. Good question! +1

Comment: Can you also pinpoint the figure numbers so that the actual issue is easier to spot?

Comment: This took me a while and my apologies - I have to add that it's an excellent article with a set of awesome authors and it was an enlightening read. Thanks so much - I learned a great deal :) I'm actually writing a paper on this stuff as we speak, so questions like this make this site so fruitful :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**
Tactile grating stimuli with a higher line density (number of lines per surface area) and applied with an equal force result in a lower amount of pressure per unit of skin area under the grating, and hence smaller afferent responses.

**Background**
In the Discussion section of the linked article [(Phillips *et al*, 1993)](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/jneuro/12/3/827.full.pdf) the authors explain on p. 838 (left column) that the reduction in the response of [SA afferents](http://neuroscience.uth.tmc.edu/s2/chapter02.html) (slowly adapting fibers) when [grating](http://neurobiography.info/teaching.php?lectureid=38&mode=handout) density is increased is due to the higher proximity of neighboring areas of stimulation, *i.e.*, the lines in the grating stimuli are more closely spaced. The authors reason that this leads to a reduction in the effective stimulus (*i.e.*, compressive strain) at the receptor terminal due to the presence of adjacent stimulus elements that distributes, and hence reduces the skin loads per line.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Phillips *et al*, *J Neurosci*; **12**(3): 927-39](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/jneuro/12/3/827.full.pdf)</sub>